# android can i turn smart phone on from message?

Tags: android

hello guys can i ((turn my phone on)) from specific  message ???
and if i can how can i doit??
can i start a service after i receive the message?
because i think it's just like the alarm it start even the phone is turned off
can any buddy solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
When the phone is turned off, there is no connection to any mobile cell or WLAN, thus no messages can be retrieved.

Comment: **thanks but someone told me that some services keep working even the phone is turned off and has enough battery charge like the alarm when you turn your mobile off and if you turn your alarm on (it will run even the phone is turned off)
but i just want to check if this is possible**

Comment: These are only local services. Wireless stuff cost too much battery power.